# is there a generic Map strategy for Apache Camel's Bindy format?

Tags: apache, apache-commons, apache-camel

Is there a builtin or standard strategy for Apache Camel's [Bindy](http://camel.apache.org/bindy.html) data format to marshal to/from `java.util.Map`s?  From what I can tell, the strategy can only be annotated into POJOs such that certain Bean properties map to/from CSV fields.

Camel's [CSV](http://camel.apache.org/csv.html) data format supports marshaling to/from `Map`s (whose keys correspond with CSV headers and values correspond with CSV fields).  Unfortunately, it depends on Apache [Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/csv/), which is still [incubating](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/) and not yet active and mature enough to be reliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Bindy is for binding to/from java beans.

You can use other components that maps to Map structures, such as camel-csv, camel-flatpack.

Comment: camel-csv appears to depend on commons-csv, which was the initial problem since commons-csv is stagnant in incubation (the flatpack component does not appear to support marshaling, which i need).  
thanks to having the source code to commons-csv, i was able to hack together two versions of commons-csv and made it functional for my camel route.  i think the lesson here is that i need to contribute to commons-csv, unless there's a more reliable CSV provider for camel-csv to consider.

Comment: i apologize - the flatpack component cannot be a producer - but it works perfectly fine within a <marshal ref="…"/> construct, solving my problem.  thanks, Claus, for your direction.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately CSV is not a sexy area to work in, so there is not many active maintained OS projects out there.