# Parse key-value text file using camel-bindy or beanio

Tags: java, csv, apache-camel, bean-io, bindy

I have an option to use either bindy or beanIO camel components to parse a csv file. Besides this csv there is dat (txt) file which contains key-value. Is it possible to parse this file to Map using one of mentioned libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **bindy** component can unmarshall a **csv file into an Object**, not directly in a Map. Here is the response of a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637539/is-there-a-generic-map-strategy-for-apache-camels-bindy-format) by Claus Ibsen.
It seems that is the same for beanIO.

However you can use the **CSV component** of Camel which will transform your file into a `List<List<String>>`.

Here is more info on bindy ([documentation on the Camel site](http://camel.apache.org/bindy.html)).

You have just to declare a DataFormat:

```
DataFormat bindy = new BindyCsvDataFormat("com.acme.model");
```

And then use it like this:

```
from("file://inbox")
  .unmarshal(bindy)
  .to("direct:whatYouWant");
```

The parameter `"com.acme.model"` correspond to the package where you define your model. Camel bindy provide a lot of option to configure the binding I encourage you to see the doc for more details, but a basic model will look like this:

```
@CsvRecord(separator = ",")
public class Order {

    @DataField(pos = 1)
    private int orderNr;

    ...
}
```